# Spring JPA Specification API with custom Query and custom response Object. Is this possible?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have researched this for a few days but can't seem to find the right information.

Here is what I need, I have a Database, with multiple tables, I need to join a few tables together to make a sort of "search" API. I have to implement the ability to dynamically search fields (from various tables in the query), sortable, with pagination.

I have found that I cannot combine the `@Query` annotation with Specification API, and I looked into using the specification API to do the joins I needed but, the problem is the root must be one table/repository.

For example:

If I have a users table that has to join on addresses, phone_numbers, and preferences

the base repository will be UserResposiory and it will return the User entity model, but I need it to return a custom DTO

AccountUserDTO which contains fields from the User, Address, PhoneNumber, and Preference entities.

Would anyone know if this is possible at all??

I am at wits end here and I really want to build this the correct way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may do this way:

Build hql query as an string, depend on how the filter condition is requested, you can build the corresponding query, eg:

```
if (hasParam(searchName)) {
  queryString = queryString + " myEntity.name = :queryName"
}
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
```

and the parameter providing

```
if (hasParam(searchName)) {
   query.setParameter("queryName", searchName);
}
...
and execute it.
```

To create a customized object, the easiest way is treating the object as an array of field:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select m.f1, m.f2, m.f3 from myTable m");
List managers = query.list();
Object[] manager = (Object[]) managers.get(0); //first row
System.out.println(manager[0]) //f1
System.out.println(manager[1]) //f2
System.out.println(manager[2]) //f3
```

There is also some other solution to select, such as

```
String query = "select new mypackage.myclass(m.f1, m.f2, m.f3) from myTable m";
```

-> And when execute the above query, it will return a list of object.

Or to be simpler, make your own view in db and map it to one entity.